# Hidden character in SQL column

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8

I've copied and pasted an SQL statement which simply adds a column into the table:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD COLUMN `favourites​` TEXT;
```

However, where I have copied and pasted, the `favourites` name has some how managed to pick up a hidden character.

I have left the hidden character in the example above for you to see/or not see as it may be!

It's `favourites?`, with what appears to be a question mark.

THE PROBLEM: I need to delete this column and re-add it manually so that the hidden character is not present. The problem is that any SQL statement I do, it doesn't recognise the the column name `favourites` because of the hidden character and I don't know how to target it.

Has anyone got any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Not quite sure why you are downvoting answers, people who are trying to help you here need to do some amount of guessing and naturally the answers may not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Do the same  use show

```
 SHOW COLUMNS FROM your_table;
```

for obtain the column name and then copy the column you need in your delete command

```
 alter table your_table  drop column  your_column_copied
```

and the add the column  with the right name

```
alter table your_table  add column  your_column
```

otherwise, if is impossible get the column_name, you can  create a temp table  without the wrong column  with create/select command

```
create table (col1, col2, col3) 
select col1,col2, col3
from you_table
```

then drop the original table and rename the temporary table  and last add your column with right name

Comment: I  have update the answer .. with a trivial suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You could use dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(800)

SELECT @sql = 'ALTER TABLE users DROP COLUMN ' + COLUMN_NAME  
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'users' and COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%favour%'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: The OP implies MySQL-based solution, not MS SQL Server. `sp_executesql` is not available in MySQL. Good thinking anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the column name by querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and prepare statement with the obtained column name. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @StrangeColumnName NVARCHAR(16) := ''

SELECT @StrangeColumnName := COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'users' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'favourites%'

DECLARE @SqlText NVARCHAR(32) := 'ALTER TABLE status DROP COLUMN ?'  
EXECUTE @SqlText USING @StrangeColumnName
```

Comment: Select `HEX(COLUMN_NAME)` so we can figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe open the information schema of the table and copy the column name from there? i don't know which Database are you using. Please update for more information.

If you have access to phpMyAdmin or, if you can create a small script to run this script:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'your_tbl_name'
```

OR

```
SHOW COLUMNS
  FROM 'your_tbl_name
```

and copy the column name from the page.

next, you can drop that column using

```
alter table your_tbl_name drop column column_name;
```

and you already know how to add a column in mysql so, i guess that should solve your problem.

*I hope you do know that you can not comment if your reputation is below 50 and if you didn't provide enough information, those who might actually have an answer for you, but have below 50 rep, will have to post it in answers. or would you like to eliminate those who are 50 rep as candidates for helping you?*

Answer (score -1):

In order to delete a column you can use:

```
alter table <tblname> drop column <colname>
```

and then after deleting the column you can add the column by writing below code:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN favourites​ TEXT;
```

Answer (score -1):

Some possibilities:

- Using phpmyadmin
- Using a tool to talk directly to the database like navicat etc